# Can I rely on a feature (web api, css, js etc.) working on chromium based browsers if it works on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, browser, cross-browser

I test new features on Chrome, Firefox and Safari before being convinced that they will work as intended for almost all of my target audience. However, I don't have time to do tests on all the browsers out there

Is testing a feature on different chromium based browsers necessary when doing web development, if I already test things on Chrome? Do different chromium based browsers implement certain things differently that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. While these browsers have the same base, functionality may not be the same in all. Some features may be missing, incomplete, or not implemented at all--at least in the moment.

It's similar to houses. All have foundations, walls, doors and windows but that doesn't mean they all look and work the same way.

One way you can find this information is https://caniuse.com/